# Special case of Leibniz formula

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-derivative, leibniz-integral-rule

I am wondering if I understand it right. Considering the following partial derivative:
$$
\partial_tF(t, x) = \partial_t\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} f(t-s, x)ds
$$
It looks to me as Leibniz should be used. So we should get
$$
\partial_t\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} f(t-s, x)ds \\ = \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \partial_t f(t-s, x)ds - f(t-a(t), x)(1-a'(t)) + f(t-b(t), x)(1-b'(t))
$$
Is this correct, or did I get something wrong?

Comment: The problem here is that the bounds of the integral are moving with $t$. This is not differentiation of a product, it's more like a composition.

Comment: Bus in the classic Leibniz rule this is the case as well. What confuses me, and where I am not absolutely sure is how to deal with the $t-s$.

Comment: Woups my bad I was misunderstanding the rule you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Applying the *[Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)* we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f\left(u(t,s),x\right)\,ds\right)}
> &\color{blue}{=f\left(u(t,b(t)),x\right)\,\frac{d}{dt}b(t)}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{-f(u(t,a(t)),x)\,\frac{d}{dt}a(t)}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{+\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f\left(u(t,s),x\right)\,ds}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
> provided the functions are appropriately differentiable.

**Example:** We look at a small example.
\begin{align*}
u(t,s)&=t-s\qquad\qquad a(t)=4t\qquad b(t)=3t^2\\
f(u(t,s),x)&=u(t,s) x\\
&=(t-s)x
\end{align*}

- The left-hand side of (1) gives
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(u(t,s),x)\,ds\right)&=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{s=4t}^{3t^2}(t-s)x\,ds\\
  &=x\frac{d}{dt}\left(ts-\frac{1}{2}s^2\bigg|_{s=4t}^{3t^2}\right)\\
  &=x\frac{d}{dt}\left(3t^3-\frac{9}{2}t^4-4t^2+8t^2\right)\\
  &\,\,\color{blue}{=x\left(-18t^3+9t^2+8t\right)}
  \end{align*}
- The right-hand side of (1) gives
  \begin{align*}
  &f\left(u(t,b(t)),x\right)\,\frac{d}{dt}b(t)-f(u(t,a(t)),x)\,\frac{d}{dt}a(t)
  +\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f\left(u(t,s),x\right)\,ds\\
  &\qquad=\left(t-\left(3t^2\right)\right)x\cdot 6t-\left(t-(4t)\right)x\cdot 4
  +\int_{4t}^{3t^2}\frac{d}{dt}(t-s)x\,ds\\
  &\qquad=\left(6t^2x-18t^3x\right)+12tx+x\int_{4t}^{3t^2}\,ds\\
  &\qquad=\left(6t^2-18t^3\right)x+12tx+\left(3t^2-4t\right)x\\
  &\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=x\left(-18t^3+9t^2+8t\right)}
  \end{align*}
  and we see according to (1) the blue marked results coincide as expected.

Comment: Thank you! So I messed up the inner derivative. I'll remember finding an example to check something like that.

Comment: @dahias42: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is useful. :-)